# Error: Reference to non-static member function must be called (2)

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code like this

```
class A {
public:

typedef int (A::*AFn)(int);
std::map<std::string, AFn> fm_;

A() {
    fm_.insert("fn1", fn);
}

int fn(int a) {
    return a;
}

};
```

I get a compile time error saying `error: reference to non-static member function must be called
fm_.insert("fn1", fn);`

Why does this happen and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `fn` is a non-static member function, a lone `fn` is not a valid expression. The only thing you can do with non-qualified `fn` in this context is *call* it: `fn(something)`. This is what the compiler is telling you.

If you want to obtain a pointer to member function `A::fn`, you have to explcitly use operator `&` and supply a qualified member name: `&A::fn`.

Comment: So, how would i declare a map which allows values to be non static member function pointers and how would i use it?

Comment: @ace007: The map is declared propely. When you *insert* elements into your map, you have to use `&A::fn` syntax instead of plain `fn`. Just do `fm_.insert("fn1", &A::fn);`. That's all.

Comment: I tried that and it says `error: no matching member function for call to 'insert' fm_.insert("fn1", &A::fn);`

Comment: @ace007: Oh, I see. `std::map` does not have a key-data `insert` method. Map expects a `std::pair` in its `insert` method. So, you have to either do `fm_.insert({ "fn1", &A::fn });` or switch to `emplace` instead of `insert` : `fm_.emplace("fn1", &A::fn);`. Or you can just do `fm_["fn1"] = &A::fn;` (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bfa5d2b07a1c58e)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it. Could you explain why it worked?

Comment: @ace007: Whihc variant is "it" specifically? As said already, `std::map` does not have an `insert` method that would take key and data as parameters. That's why your version didn't work. The versions that I used do exist. Which is why they work.